# ecryptfs and ssh pubkey login - How automount and other stuff?

Tags: ssh, login, automount, ecryptfs

I have moved my ssh authorized_keys to an /etc/ssh/ subfolder, so I can login with pubkeys and have root in control of ssh access, but there are 2 problems left.

It does not automount my users ecryptfs and when I manually mount it my terminal settings arent loaded, things like aliases and paths. How can I make this happen on sshlogin?

Comment: At least these days `AuthorizedKeysFile` can take several paths where to look up the authorized keys. So you could point it at the traditional location as well as something "outside".

Answer (score 5):

As already reported, ecryptfs does use your password to "unwrap" the mount key, and if you don't provide it when loggin in, it won't work.

However...

If you do run `ecryptfs-umount-private` to unmount the encrypted home, followed by a `mkdir ~/.ecryptfs/presets ; ln -s ~/.ecryptfs/presets/.profile ~/.profile` and remount the encrypted home with `ecryptfs-mount-private`. You will have a file in "~/.ecryptfs/presets/" called ".profile" which will be sourced on every connection. (If you it is unnecessary to be able to tweak this file with an mounted private home, you could just as well just create a real textfile called .profile in your unmounted home, instead of the softlink above).

The content of ~/.ecryptfs/presets/.profile (or unmounted "~/.profile"), could be something in the line of

```
ecryptfs-mount-private && cd ~ && . ./.profile
```

That will make sure your home is unencrypted, or otherwise ask you of your password to unencrypt it, change directory to your new mounted home, and source the ordinary .profile, which will set up your shell as you are accustomed to.

Comment: Why is this not the highest-voted answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do pubkey logins and have automount work. The login *password* is needed to decrypt the mount key. The login password isn't available when doing pubkey-based logins.

Comment: Factually true, but extremely unhelpful compared to the other answer. After all the inquirer also asked how to make it work ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made it possible by copying .profile to the home folder when private is unmounted. So aliases and colors work.
Now remote X apps wont show "because of wrong authentication". It works when already logged in physical and then sshed.